# Getting error using gender.py

Tags: python

am trying to tell gender by first name.
I been using this code from: 
[https://github.com/block8437/gender.py/blob/master/gender.py][1]

```
import requests, json

def getGenders(names):
url = ""
cnt = 0
if not isinstance(names,list):
    names = [names,]    
for name in names:
    if url == "":
        url = "name[0]=" + name
    else:
        cnt += 1
        url = url + "&name[" + str(cnt) + "]=" + name


req = requests.get("https://api.genderize.io?" + url)
results = json.loads(req.text)

retrn = []
for result in results:
    if result["gender"] is not None:
        retrn.append((result["gender"], result["probability"], result["count"]))
    else:
        retrn.append((u'None',u'0.0',0.0))
return retrn
```

Everything was working for 2 days, I have not change anything in the code. I been passing different names in it on and off for 2 days. Suddenly I got this error:

> string indices must be integers

on this line:

```
if result["gender"] is not None:
```

First, I want to know why this would suddenly happen? Second, How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably `results` somehow only had a list containing one string in it. That would mean that you're trying to get the "gender"th character of `result`. Not really sure why that would happen though.

Comment: Would need to see the data.

Comment: See the responses from https://api.genderize.io/?name=peter and https://api.genderize.io/?name[0]=peter, which return different formats. In my opinion this is bad API design- the response for a given endpoint should be consistent regardless of the request. Would have been better with separate endpoints for https://api.genderize.io/name and https://api.genderize.io/names, or have a single endpoint that always returns a list

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a dictionary iterates through the keys in a dictionary.

```
results = {"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":"0.99","count":796}
[result for result in results] # ['count', 'gender', 'name', 'probability']
```

Iterating through a list iterates through the items of a list.

```
results = [{"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":"0.99","count":796}]
[result for result in results] # [{'count': 796, 'gender': 'male', 'name': 'peter', 'probability': '0.99'}]
```

According to the API description at https://genderize.io/, there are two response formats: a json object for a single name lookup (which `json.loads` would return as a dictionary), and a list of objects for multiple lookups (which `json.loads` would return as a list of dictionaries). See the response for

https://api.genderize.io/?name=peter

compared to

https://api.genderize.io/?name[0]=peter

It seems like your error is the result of getting a response in the first format when you are expecting the second. Why might this have changed? Thats a question for the API you are using. It looks to me like your request should always be in the multi-name request format but I can't speak for how they are *actually* responding.

As for fixing this, you could check the type and wrap naked dictionaries in a list:

```
retrn = []
if not isinstance(results,  list):
    results =[results]

for result in results:
    if result["gender"] is not None:
        retrn.append((result["gender"], result["probability"], result["count"]))
    else:
        retrn.append((u'None',u'0.0',0.0))
```